# `pipenv install` successfully installs a package from a GitLab project's PyPI registry, but then fails in the locking step

Tags: python, gitlab, pypi, pipenv

I'm using pipenv to install a package from the PyPI registry of a private GitLab project, like this:

```
pipenv install --index https://<my-gitlab-instance>/api/v4/projects/<my-project-id>/packages/pypi/simple <my-python-package>
```

The actual installation of the package succeeds, but the command later fails in the locking step. Here's part of the command's output:

```
Installing <my-python-package>...
Adding <my-python-package> to Pipfile's [packages]...
Installation Succeeded
Pipfile.lock (xxxxxx) out of date, updating to (yyyyyy)...
Locking [dev-packages] dependencies...
Locking [packages] dependencies...
           Building requirements...
Resolving dependencies...
Locking Failed!

CRITICAL:pipenv.patched.notpip._internal.resolution.resolvelib.factory:Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement <my-python-package> (from versions: none)
```

The error message says it can't find any version of the package... but it already found and installed a version of the package, so that makes no sense.

I confirmed that the package was installed by importing stuff from it in a python console in the pipenv virtual environment.

I'm using pipenv version 2021.11.15.

Any idea why the locking step fails or how I can debug it?

Answer (score 4):

I think this is a pipenv bug, and I've reported it [here](https://github.com/pypa/pipenv/issues/4873).

The `pipenv install` command generates a Pipfile that looks like this:

```
[[source]]
url = "https://pypi.org/simple"
verify_ssl = true
name = "pypi"

[packages]
<my-package> = {version = "*", index = "https://<my-gitlab-instance>/api/v4/projects/<my-project-id>/packages/pypi/simple"}
...
```

I think that's correct, yet `pipenv lock` fails on it, so that's apparently a bug in `pipenv lock`.

A workaround is to manually factor out the private PyPI registry as an additional `[[source]]` block, like so:

```
[[source]]
url = "https://pypi.org/simple"
verify_ssl = true
name = "pypi"

[[source]]
url = "https://<my-gitlab-instance>/api/v4/projects/<my-project-id>/packages/pypi/simple"
verify_ssl = true
name = "mypypi"

[packages]
<my-package> = {version = "*", index = "mypypi"}
...
```

Comment: Just a note, you can also inject variables into the url.  
url = "https://$USERNAME:${PASSWORD}@mypypi.example.com/simple" More on this here: https://pipenv-fork.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced.html#injecting-credentials-into-pipfiles-via-environment-variables